# GSON Parsing error

Tags: android, gson

This is my json,

```
{"status":"success","data":{"name":"Test","mob_no":"8089647076","country_prefix":"+91","email":""}}
```

please note that

```
"email":""
```

when i try to parse this using gson its throwing error

```
03-16 16:50:29.019: E/AndroidRuntime(11039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gsonsample/com.example.gsonsample.MainActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 1 column 11
```

---

My model class

```
public class APIBase {

String status;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

Data data;
}
```

---

Data model class

```
public class Data {



String name, mob_no, country_prefix;

List<Review> reviews;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMob_no() {
    return mob_no;
}

public void setMob_no(String mob_no) {
    this.mob_no = mob_no;
}

public String getCountry_prefix() {
    return country_prefix;
}

public void setCountry_prefix(String country_prefix) {
    this.country_prefix = country_prefix;
}

public List<Review> getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}

public void setReviews(List<Review> reviews) {
    this.reviews = reviews;
}



}
```

---

this is my code to parse the json

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(getString(
            R.string.json3).trim()));
    reader.setLenient(true);

    APIBase base = gson.fromJson(reader, APIBase.class);
    Log.v("status", base.getStatus() + "");
```

this is my json in xml

```
<string name="json3">{"status":"success","data":{"name":"Test","mob_no":"8089647076","country_prefix":"+91","email":""}}</string>
```

i am learning the gson methode.

i found that its not necessary for variables for all fields in the json

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you add your model class?

Comment: Please show some code, the json looks ok.

Comment: i added the model class

Comment: How about the Data class?

Comment: hi, i added Data class tooo

Comment: How did you get your Json string, which is shown here, can you try a test with constructing json string with Gson and deserializing, since the json string given here, is perfect and passes ...

Comment: i am learning the gson. i just typed those json  and it can parsed through jsoneditoronlin.com with out error.

Comment: as i mentioned the problem is for   "email":""   if i put some value then its ok. eg: "email":"sample@gmail.com"

Comment: can you add the code where you are ingesting the json string and converting it to the model.

Comment: i think its fyn, the gson only ignores if there is no variable for any field. 
i tested it.

Comment: i commented the "status" variable and its getters and setters
then i tried 

APIBase base = gson.fromJson(reader, APIBase.class);
  Log.v("status", base.getData().getName() + "");

and its working

Comment: Can you also add the content of your string.xml?

Comment: {"status":"success","data":{"name":"Test","mob_no":"8089647076","country_prefix":"+91","email":""}}

Comment: I need the actual xml formatted one. I just tried your code with and it worked on my side. I am thinking that the string is not well formatted in the xml file

Comment: but y i get jsonsyntaxerror ???

Comment: can u give me your xml ???

Comment: <string name="json3">{"status":"success","data":{"name":"Test","mob_no":"8089647076","country_prefix":"+91","email":"email"}}</string>  this is my xml, single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your string.xml:

```
  <string name="test_string">
   {\"status\":\"success\",\"data\":{\"name\":\"Test\",\"mob_no\":\"8089647076\",\"country_prefix\":\"+91\",\"email\":\"\"}}
  </string>
```

Comment: your string is working. can you tell me is there any way to cast normal string to this style ??

Comment: Just remember for the future to escape single and double quotes in your string resources ;)

Comment: You can do it this way: \\"

Comment: should be `replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");`. Why do you need this anyways?

Comment: This is only the case for when you put your string in string.xml. You should not need to do this when you get your string from the server

Comment: thats fyn.  i heard gson is awesome and am trying to learn that. any way,  thats a lot of knowledge thank you hoomi. :)